# Remove div element without removing anything inside it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I remove div `class="2"` only?  I need to keep div 1 and ul and li.

Result:

```
<div class="1">      
  <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="1">
  <!--<div class="2">-->
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unwrap

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) that remove the parents of element but keep self.

```
$(".2 > ul").unwrap();
```

```js
$(".2 > ul").unwrap();
console.log($(".1")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```